# Why would CUPS be duplicating pages when you specify how many copes to print?

Tags: cups

I'm running ArchLinux with a CUPS server on it. I am using an gutuenprint driver for a Sinfonia printer. Whenever I tell cups to print more than one copy of a 1-page document, it duplicates the pages by the amount of copies, and then continues to print those amounts of copies. So the amount of pages that I end up getting are N^N. If I ask for 10 copies of a 1 page document, the printer will make 10 copies of a 10 page document. I'm sending a JPEG file to the printer, if that makes any different.

I feel like the CUPS filters may be duplicating the pages based on copies, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In the GutenPrint driver for my printer, it was setting the attribute `*cupsManualCopies` set to `True`. Setting the value to `False` resolved the issue.